# Why the FCN32 output is a black image (all pixels have zero values)?

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, deeplearning4j

I am trying to get the output from FCN 32. I trained FCN32 with pascalcontext-fcn32-heavy.caffemodel pre-trained model. I could run for grayscale images with 5 classes. However, during inference, the output is all zero (a black image). This is inference code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import sys
import scipy.io as sio
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
import caffe
    caffe.set_device(0) 
    caffe.set_mode_gpu()

    # load image, subtract mean, and make dims C x H x W for Caffe

   img_name='/home/ss/caffe-pascalcontext-fcn32s/dataset/Test/PNG/image-061-023.png'    #+
    im = Image.open(img_name)

    in_ = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
    in_ = np.expand_dims(in_, axis=0)               #+
    print in_.shape
    #Read mean image
    '''####################'''
    mean_blob = caffe_pb2.BlobProto()
    with open('/home/ss/caffe-pascalcontext-fcn32s/input/FCN32_mean.binaryproto') as f:
        mean_blob.ParseFromString(f.read())
    mean_array = np.asarray(mean_blob.data, dtype=np.float32).reshape(
        (mean_blob.channels, mean_blob.height, mean_blob.width))
    in_ -= mean_array

    net_root = '/home/ss/caffe-pascalcontext-fcn32s'

    MODEL_DEF = net_root + '/deploy.prototxt'
    PRETRAINED = net_root + '/snapshot/FCN32s_train_iter_40000.caffemodel'
    # load net
    #net = caffe.Net('deploy.prototxt', 'snapshot/train_iter_640000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
    net = caffe.Net(MODEL_DEF,PRETRAINED, caffe.TEST)
    #net = caffe.Net('deploy.prototxt', 'snapshot_bak1/train_iter_400000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)

    # shape for input (data blob is N x C x H x W), set data
    # put img to net
    net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, *in_.shape)  # 1: batch size, *in_.shape 3 channel ?
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = in_

    # run net and take argmax for prediction
    output = net.forward()

    # print
    def print_param(output):
        # the blobs
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the blobs'
        for k, v in net.blobs.items():
            print k, v.data.shape

        # the parameters
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the paramsters'
        for k, v in net.params.items():
            print k, v[0].data.shape

        # the conv layer weights
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the conv layer weights'
        print net.params['conv1_1'][0].data

        # the data blob 
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the data blob'
        print net.blobs['data'].data

        # the conv1_1 blob
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the conv1_1 blob'
        print net.blobs['conv1_1'].data

        # the pool1 blob
        print '--------------------------'
        print 'the pool1 blob'
        print net.blobs['pool1'].data

        weights = net.blobs['fc6'].data[0]
        print 'blobs fc6'
        print np.unique(weights)
        weights = net.blobs['fc7'].data[0]
        print 'blobs fc7'
        print np.unique(weights)
        weights = net.blobs['score_fr_sign'].data[0]
        print 'blobs score_fr_sign'
        print np.unique(weights)
        weights = net.blobs['upscore_sign'].data[0]
        print 'blobs upscore_sign'
        print np.unique(weights)
        weights = net.blobs['score'].data[0]
            print weights.shape             #+
            sio.savemat('scores.mat',{'weights':weights})   #+
        print 'blobs score'
        print np.unique(weights)

    print_param(output)

    out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
    print out           #+

    #np.savetxt("vote", out, fmt="%02d")
    np.savetxt("vote", out, fmt="%d")

    print im.height
    print im.width
    print out.shape, len(out.shape)

    def array2img(out):
        out1 = np.array(out, np.unit8)
        img = Image.fromarray(out1,'L')
        for x in range(img.size[0]):
            for y in range(img.size[1]):
                if not img.getpixel((x, y)) == 0:
                    print 'PLz', str(img.getpixel((x, y)))

        img.show()


    def show_pred_img(file_name):
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        lines = file.read().split('\n')

        #img_name = str(sys.argv[1])
        im = Image.open(img_name)
        im_pixel = im.load()

        img = Image.new('RGB', im.size, "black")
        pixels = img.load()

        w, h = 0, 0
        for l in lines:
            w = 0
            if len(l) > 0:
                word = l.split(' ')
                for x in word:
                    if int(x) == 1:
                        pixels[w, h] = im_pixel[w, h]
                    w += 1
                h += 1
        print im.size
        #img.show()
        img.save(img_name+'_result.png')
    show_pred_img('vote')
```

This the log information of inference:

```
the blobs
data (1, 1, 256, 256)
data_input_0_split_0 (1, 1, 256, 256)
data_input_0_split_1 (1, 1, 256, 256)
conv1_1 (1, 64, 454, 454)
conv1_2 (1, 64, 454, 454)
pool1 (1, 64, 227, 227)
conv2_1 (1, 128, 227, 227)
conv2_2 (1, 128, 227, 227)
pool2 (1, 128, 114, 114)
conv3_1 (1, 256, 114, 114)
conv3_2 (1, 256, 114, 114)
conv3_3 (1, 256, 114, 114)
pool3 (1, 256, 57, 57)
conv4_1 (1, 512, 57, 57)
conv4_2 (1, 512, 57, 57)
conv4_3 (1, 512, 57, 57)
pool4 (1, 512, 29, 29)
conv5_1 (1, 512, 29, 29)
conv5_2 (1, 512, 29, 29)
conv5_3 (1, 512, 29, 29)
pool5 (1, 512, 15, 15)
fc6 (1, 4096, 9, 9)
fc7 (1, 4096, 9, 9)
score_fr_sign (1, 5, 9, 9)
upscore_sign (1, 5, 320, 320)
score (1, 5, 256, 256)
--------------------------
the paramsters
conv1_1 (64, 1, 3, 3)
conv1_2 (64, 64, 3, 3)
conv2_1 (128, 64, 3, 3)
conv2_2 (128, 128, 3, 3)
conv3_1 (256, 128, 3, 3)
conv3_2 (256, 256, 3, 3)
conv3_3 (256, 256, 3, 3)
conv4_1 (512, 256, 3, 3)
conv4_2 (512, 512, 3, 3)
conv4_3 (512, 512, 3, 3)
conv5_1 (512, 512, 3, 3)
conv5_2 (512, 512, 3, 3)
conv5_3 (512, 512, 3, 3)
fc6 (4096, 512, 7, 7)
fc7 (4096, 4096, 1, 1)
score_fr_sign (5, 4096, 1, 1)
upscore_sign (5, 1, 64, 64)
--------------------------
the conv layer weights
[[[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]]

...
 .
 .
 .       

 [[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]]]
--------------------------
the data blob
[[[[ 29.32040787  20.31391525  20.30148506 ...,  10.41113186  11.42486095
      6.42949915]
   [ 33.32374954  21.31280136  22.30037117 ...,   9.40779209  10.42189217
      8.43079758]
   [ 36.32300568  25.30816269  25.29183578 ...,  10.40148449  11.41818142
     10.42838573]
   ..., 
   [ 34.64990616  31.65658569  30.65714264 ...,   4.           2.99981451
      0.99962896]
   [ 39.65788651  33.65769958  29.65974045 ...,   5.99981451   4.99944353
      0.99888682]
   [ 41.6641922   34.66493607  30.66567802 ...,   5.99962902   2.99907231
      3.99833035]]]]
--------------------------
the conv1_1 blob
[[[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  ..., 
  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]]]
--------------------------
the pool1 blob
[[[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  ..., 
  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   ..., 
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]]]
blobs fc6
[ 0.]
blobs fc7
[ 0.]
blobs score_fr_sign
[-1.61920226 -1.34294271  0.07809996  0.60521388  2.2788291 ]
blobs upscore_sign
[-1.61920238 -1.61920226 -1.61920214 ...,  2.27882886  2.2788291
  2.27882934]
(5, 256, 256)
blobs score
[-1.61920238 -1.61920226 -1.61920214 -1.59390223 -1.59390211 -1.5689975
 -1.54330218 -1.54330206 -1.51918805 -1.49270213 -1.49270201 -1.4709599
 -1.46937859 -1.44210207 -1.44210196 -1.42273164 -1.41956913 -1.39150202
 -1.3915019  -1.37608469 -1.37450349 -1.36975968 -1.34294283 -1.34294271
 -1.3429426  -1.34090197 -1.34090185 -1.32943773 -1.32627523 -1.32195926
 -1.31995022 -1.30130363 -1.2903018  -1.28437209 -1.2827909  -1.27999234
 -1.27999222 -1.27804708 -1.27014089 -1.25999236 -1.23970175 -1.23930645
 -1.23802543 -1.23802531 -1.23614395 -1.22981894 -1.22033143 -1.21999264
 -1.21868122 -1.19605839 -1.19605827 -1.195822   -1.19424069 -1.18949699
 -1.1891017  -1.18910158 -1.18159068 -1.17999291 -1.17736995 -1.17052197
 -1.15409136 -1.15233755 -1.14917505 -1.14285004 -1.14130461 -1.13999307
 -1.13850164 -1.13850152 -1.13605869 -1.13336253 -1.12071252 -1.11212444
 -1.11043441 -1.1088531  -1.10410941 -1.10261631 -1.09999335 -1.09620309
 -1.09474754 -1.08790159 -1.08790147 -1.08513427 -1.07090306 -1.07015753
 -1.07015741 -1.06853116 -1.06536865 -1.06523943 -1.06392801 -1.05999362
 -1.05904365 -1.05343628 -1.04955614 -1.03730154 -1.03730142 -1.03690612
 -1.02820921 -1.02819049 -1.02786267 -1.02662802 -1.02523971 -1.0218842
 -1.02109361 -1.0199939  -1.013978   -1.01212502 -1.00290918 -0.99179727
 -0.99048585 -0.98867792 -0.98788732 -0.98670143 -0.98670137 -0.9865514
 -0.98622358 -0.98622352 -0.98472482 -0.97999406 -0.97839981 -0.97128415
 -0.97081381 -0.9689123  -0.95626229 -0.95573193 -0.95310903 -0.94914663
 -0.94786316 -0.94756538 -0.9442566  -0.94425654 -0.94282162 -0.94044977
 -0.93999434 -0.93491536 -0.92950261 -0.9238466  -0.92097807 -0.91966659
 -0.9157322  -0.91040593 -0.90961534 -0.90917486 -0.90724343 -0.90228963
 -0.90091842 -0.89999455 -0.89143091 -0.88819134 -0.88622415 -0.88360125
 -0.8787809  -0.87835538 -0.87324655 -0.8716653  -0.87048656 -0.86692154
 -0.86032271 -0.86032265 -0.85999483 -0.85901529 -0.85278171 -0.85147029
 -0.84794647 -0.84753585 -0.84688014 -0.8409785  -0.83608711 -0.8329246
 -0.83179826 -0.8265996  -0.81999505 -0.81933933 -0.81835574 -0.81835568
 -0.81711209 -0.81671637 -0.81147051 -0.80556893 -0.80360168 -0.80050892
 -0.79892766 -0.79418391 -0.79310995 -0.78720838 -0.78627765 -0.7858969
 -0.78196251 -0.77999532 -0.77540517 -0.76622486 -0.76493073 -0.76176822
 -0.75544322 -0.75507742 -0.75442165 -0.75245446 -0.7472086  -0.73933983
 -0.73093385 -0.72935259 -0.72884804 -0.72460884 -0.72425795 -0.72294647
 -0.71901208 -0.71245474 -0.70327443 -0.69693691 -0.6937744  -0.69343841
 -0.69081551 -0.68556964 -0.67770082 -0.66452122 -0.66393042 -0.66293997
 -0.66261894 -0.65868455 -0.65212721 -0.63442242 -0.63210559 -0.63179946
 -0.6265536  -0.60622585 -0.60491437 -0.60127115 -0.60097998 -0.57802927
 -0.57540637 -0.55114424 -0.54983276 -0.52425915 -0.49868551  0.02900147
  0.03048873  0.03197598  0.03205225  0.03346324  0.03361578  0.03495049
  0.0351793   0.03525557  0.03643775  0.03674283  0.03689536  0.037925
  0.03830635  0.03853516  0.03861143  0.03941226  0.03986987  0.04017495
  0.04032749  0.04089952  0.0414334   0.04181475  0.04204356  0.04211983
  0.04238677  0.04299692  0.04345454  0.04375962  0.04387403  0.04391216
  0.04456045  0.04509434  0.04536128  0.04547568  0.04570449  0.04578076
  0.04612397  0.04673413  0.04684854  0.04719175  0.04749683  0.04759216
  0.04764936  0.0476875   0.04837392  0.04890781  0.04925102  0.04928916
  0.04951797  0.04959423  0.05001372  0.05003278  0.05003279  0.05062388
  0.05108149  0.05138657  0.05153911  0.05165351  0.05233994  0.05247341
  0.05247341  0.05287382  0.05325517  0.05348398  0.05356025  0.054056
  0.05466616  0.05491403  0.05491403  0.05512378  0.05542885  0.05558139
  0.05645849  0.05699238  0.05735466  0.05735466  0.05737372  0.05760253
  0.0576788   0.05886098  0.05931859  0.05962367  0.05977621  0.05979528
  0.05979528  0.06126347  0.06164481  0.06187363  0.06194989  0.0622359
  0.06223591  0.06366596  0.06397104  0.06412357  0.06467653  0.06606845
  0.06629726  0.06637353  0.06711715  0.06847093  0.06862348  0.06955777
  0.06955778  0.07087342  0.0709497   0.0719984   0.0719984   0.07327592
  0.07443902  0.07443903  0.0756784   0.07687964  0.07687965  0.07809995
  0.07809996  0.07809997  0.22473885  0.23626392  0.24778898  0.24838002
  0.25931406  0.26049611  0.27083912  0.27261221  0.27320322  0.28236419
  0.28472832  0.28591037  0.29388925  0.29684439  0.29861748  0.29920852
  0.30541432  0.3089605   0.31132463  0.31250668  0.31693938  0.3210766
  0.32403174  0.32580483  0.32639587  0.32846448  0.33319271  0.33673888
  0.33910298  0.33998954  0.34028506  0.34530881  0.349446    0.35151461
  0.35240114  0.35417423  0.35476527  0.35742489  0.36215314  0.36303967
  0.36569929  0.36806342  0.36880219  0.36880222  0.36924547  0.36954099
  0.37486026  0.37899747  0.38165709  0.38195261  0.3837257   0.38431671
  0.38756737  0.38771513  0.38771516  0.39229563  0.39584181  0.39820591
  0.39938796  0.40027452  0.40559378  0.40662807  0.40973097  0.41268614
  0.4144592   0.41505024  0.41889194  0.42362016  0.42554098  0.42554101
  0.42716634  0.42953047  0.43071252  0.43750936  0.44164655  0.44445392
  0.44445395  0.44460171  0.44637477  0.44696581  0.45612678  0.45967296
  0.46203706  0.46321911  0.46336687  0.4633669   0.4747442   0.47769934
  0.47947243  0.48006344  0.48227981  0.48227984  0.49336162  0.49572572
  0.49690777  0.50119275  0.51197904  0.5137521   0.51434314  0.52010566
  0.52010572  0.53059644  0.53177851  0.53901857  0.53901863  0.54921389
  0.54980487  0.55793154  0.56783128  0.57684445  0.57684451  0.58644873
  0.59575737  0.59575742  0.60521382  0.60521388  0.60521394  0.84621561
  0.88961124  0.93300694  0.93523234  0.97640258  0.98085344  1.01979828
  1.02647448  1.02869999  1.06319392  1.07209563  1.07654643  1.10658967
  1.11771667  1.12439299  1.12661839  1.14998531  1.16333783  1.17223942
  1.17669034  1.19338095  1.20895886  1.22008598  1.22676229  1.22898769
  1.23677659  1.25458002  1.26793253  1.27683413  1.28017235  1.28128505
  1.30020106  1.31577897  1.32356799  1.32690609  1.3335824   1.3358078
  1.34582222  1.36362553  1.36696362  1.37697804  1.38587976  1.38866138
  1.3886615   1.39033055  1.39144325  1.41147208  1.42704999  1.43706429
  1.43817711  1.44485331  1.4470787   1.45931852  1.45987487  1.45987499
  1.47712183  1.49047434  1.49937606  1.50382698  1.50716507  1.52719378
  1.53108823  1.53108835  1.5427717   1.55389881  1.56057513  1.56280053
  1.57726574  1.59506905  1.6023016   1.60230172  1.60842156  1.61732328
  1.62177408  1.6473664   1.66294444  1.67351508  1.6735152   1.67407143
  1.68074775  1.68297315  1.71746719  1.7308197   1.7397213   1.74417222
  1.74472845  1.74472857  1.78756785  1.79869497  1.80537117  1.80759656
  1.81594181  1.81594193  1.81594205  1.85766852  1.86657023  1.87102103
  1.88715529  1.88715541  1.9277693   1.9344455   1.9366709   1.95836878
  1.99786997  2.00232077  2.02958202  2.02958226  2.06797075  2.07019615
  2.10079551  2.10079575  2.1380713   2.17200899  2.20817208  2.24322224
  2.24322248  2.27882886  2.2788291   2.27882934]
256
256
(256, 256) 2
(256, 256)
```

I have two major questions:

1. I am wondering why the output is black? and
2. How can I know when to stop running the algorithm (i.e., iteration
   number)? I really do not know what is the optimum iteration number and
   loss value that I can stop fine tuning in that stage. I stopped
   training in `40,000 iterations`, I have no idea about this.
3. Is it necessary that the result of segmentation be a grayscale image
   as well (like input), or creating RGB result image does not make any
   difference in the output?

I really do not know how much I am doing the right way. Quite CONFUSED :(
Does anyone have any suggestion? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: See also: [Debugging neural networks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41493375/562769)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your labels' data type is uint8! I had the same problem!

Also make sure that you have weight filler like below in your prototxt before training!

```
layer {
name: "myupscore2"
type: "Deconvolution"
bottom: "myscore_fr"
top: "myupscore2"
param {
lr_mult: 5
}
convolution_param {
group :2
num_output: 2
weight_filler: { type: "bilinear" }
bias_term: false
kernel_size: 4
stride: 16
 }
 }
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks Arghavan, Yes I had already added the weight_fille. the loss in Iteration 0 is `loss = 105476` . is it normal ? My images are grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it usually depends on your image size! Have you checked your data type? Both your images and groundtruths should be uint8!

Also have you add the "group" line to your Deconv layer?

Best

Comment: Yes I have added `group` which 5 (the number of classes) in my case. How can I check the data type in Python. I have saved both images and ground truth into uint8 in Matlab. Would it be possible that may change while converting into LMDB? Thanks again

Comment: welcome to SO. Thank you for the valuable inputs and answers, but please do not post many answers to a single question if you can simply edit your existing answer.

Comment: If your data is saved uint8 just double check your labels and see if pixels' intensities are from 0 to 4 (#of your classes).