# Keras always output the same thing

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I trained a keras model inspired by the Inception Model on Tensorflow backend.
The problem is, the ouput is always the same, for differents images I tested.

However, model.evaluate give me a high accuracy percentage, so, the model seems to work.

Have you an idea ? Thanks!

Comment: Much more information is needed, your dataset is probably highly unbalanced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my CIFAR 100 CNN model mainly predict two classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705400/why-does-my-cifar-100-cnn-model-mainly-predict-two-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.

I just forgot to preprocess my input for the prediction.

All is clear now!