# bad results on binary classification with very little data

Tags: deep-learning, keras, classification

I only have 141 pictures, 71 of each class (medical images)
and I want to classify them. I know this is very little data so I want to use augmentation.

My problem is I can't get pass the 0.5 accuracy even on the training data when using augmentation!

When I train only on the 141 images I can get to 80%, so it must mean that I'm using augmentation wrong?

Would love if anyone here can understand what am I doing wrong:

**my model:**

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import optimizers
K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(256,256,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
#normalize
meanImg = np.mean(X , axis = 0)
stdImg = np.std(X , axis = 0)
X_norm = (X - meanImg)  / (stdImg + 0.0001)


# we will split again without normalizing, the DataGenerator will normalize
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_norm, y,test_size=0.2)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
                                 featurewise_std_normalization = True)

train_datagen.fit(X_train)
test_datagen.fit(X_test)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size = 16 , save_to_dir='train',save_prefix='aug')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow(X_test,y_test,batch_size =16 , save_to_dir='test' , save_prefix = 'aug')
```

This gives bad results:

```
batch_size = 16
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000// batch_size,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=400 // batch_size)
model.save_weights('first_try.h5')  # always save your weights after training or during training
```

This gives good results:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16,
          epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you fit on `train_datagen` and `test_datagen` and then train with `fit_generator` or `fit()`? This doesn´t seem to make any sense. I would also recommend to use `flow_from_directory` and augment continuously through your few samples.

Answer (score 1):

I would first use a simpler network and try to get non-trivial results. Also, try to use the same datagen which you fit on the train set for the test set.

Also: Did you really apply the same preprocessing in both cases? I vaguely remember that `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` was often applied the wrong way... just disable the augmentation (also the other options) and see what happens. Then you can conclude if your augmentation is wrong.

See also: [Debugging neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488279/neural-network-always-predicts-the-same-class/41493375#41493375)

Comment: I did use a simpler network. I got near perfect score on my training data but not very good ones on my validation. in other words , overfitting. that's why I then tried using more data with augmentation

Comment: You should only change one thing at a time. What happens with the simpler network but with augmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more conv layers or increasing your kernel for the conv filters.
You're using 3 conv layers with 3x3 filters so your receptive field is just 7x7.

I also suggest to use BatchNormalization:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(256,256,1), activation='relu'))
BatchNormalization(axis=1)
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
BatchNormalization(axis=1),
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
BatchNormalization(axis=1),
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64), activation='relu')
BatchNormalization(axis=1)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```