# ConvNet Which has 98% Test Accuracy, Always wrong at predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently building a convolutional neural network to distinguish clear ECG images from ECG images with noise.

With Noise :

[image: With Noise Sample ECG Image]

Without Noise :

[image: Without Noise Sample ECG Image]

**My Problem**

So I did build a convnet using keras above tensorflow and trained it several times but all the time, it has like **99% of Training Accuracy, 99% Validation Accuracy and 98% of Testing accuracy**. But when I predict an image, it always give me `[0]`.

[image: Accuracies of Training, validation and Testing]

Most of the times, my model early stops at epoch 3 or 4 with 99% of accuracy in both training and validation. It almost all the time given 98% or 99% accuracy in first epoch or second epoch.

**My Model**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation,Dropout,Flatten,Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.layers import ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="./logs",histogram_freq=0,write_graph=True,write_images=True)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=2,verbose=1)

# Variables
batchSize = 15
num_of_samples = 15000
num_of_testing_samples = 3750
num_of_val_samples = 2000

training_imGenProp = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                width_shift_range=0.02,
                                height_shift_range=0.02,
                                horizontal_flip=False,
                                fill_mode='nearest'
                                )   

testing_imGenProp = ImageDataGenerator(
                                rotation_range=5,
                                horizontal_flip=False,
                                fill_mode='nearest'
                                )

val_imGenProp = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                rotation_range=5,
                                zoom_range=0.2,
                                horizontal_flip=False,
                                fill_mode='nearest'
                                )                                    



# Create the model                                    
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(374,0),input_shape=(74,448,3)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.8))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.summary()

adam = Adam(lr=0.00005)
classifier.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=adam,metrics=['accuracy'])

training_imGen = training_imGenProp.flow_from_directory(
                                'Directory\Training',
                                target_size=(74,448),
                                batch_size=batchSize,
                                class_mode='binary',

                                )

testing_imGen = testing_imGenProp.flow_from_directory(
                                'Directory\Testing',
                                target_size=(74,448),
                                batch_size=batchSize,
                                class_mode='binary',

                                )   

val_imGen = testing_imGenProp.flow_from_directory(
                                'Directory\Validation', 
                                target_size=(74,448),
                                batch_size=batchSize,
                                class_mode='binary',

                                )                                   

classifier.fit_generator(
                            training_imGen,
                            callbacks = [tensorboard,earlystop], 
                            steps_per_epoch=num_of_samples // batchSize,
                            epochs=30, 
                            validation_data = val_imGen,
                            validation_steps = num_of_val_samples // batchSize
                         ) 

score, acc = classifier.evaluate_generator(
                        testing_imGen,
                        num_of_testing_samples // batchSize,
                        verbose = 0
                    )     
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
classifier.save('Directory\Config_10_Model.h5')
```

**Notes**

I used 0.0005 Learning rate to stop this model being early stopped at 2nd or 3rd epoch. Also I've separated images for training, testing and validation under three folders and have 1020,375,200 images respectively for training,testing and validation (Which means Training folder alone has 2040 images since I have two classes. Each class have same number of images). So no images will be reused under any circumstances.

Also, before I'm rescaling images by 1./255 in ImageDataGenerator, My model had 50% of accuracy in training, validation and 54% in testing. But after using rescaling, this early stopping happened frequently and accuracy was 99% almost all the time.

I didn't use rescaling for test images purposely. But still receive 98% accuracy and yet fails desperately at predicting. Since I've `with noise` and `without noise` folders under training folder, My output class should be with noise or without noise. Since with Noise comes first in alphabetical order, I believe `[0]` class says `With Noise` and `[1]` should be for `Without Noise`. But if I input without noise image to model, it still gives me `[0]`.

Below is the code I use to predict trained model.

```
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

model = load_model('Directory\Config_10_Model.h5')

test_image = image.load_img('Path_to_Without_Noise_Image\image3452.png', target_size = (74, 448))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = test_image/255
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
y_classes = result.argmax(axis=-1)
print(y_classes)
```

I don't know why this happenes even though I never used same images for testing, validation or training. Can someone help me with this? I tried everything and trained model with different hyper parameters but everytime this model output `[0]`.

Comment: What is your confusion matrix? Is the resulting prediction always (0 or 1)? what is your python version (2 or 3) , try test_image/255.0 (in python 2: x/255 => 0 instead of fraction )

Comment: did you happen to have very very unbalanced samples? Like 99% of one class and 1% of another class?

Comment: @sathyz Yes. Result should be either 0 or 1 since this is a binary classification. I'm using python 3.5 with Tensorflow-GPU. I did try with test_image/255.0 but still get the same result.

Comment: @DanielMöller Nope. Both of my categories has same amount of images. ex: Under training, With Noise has 1020 images and Without Noise has 1020 images. Same applies to validation and Testing folders.

Comment: Although it turned out to be something different, please note my guide for [debugging neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493375/562769)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing binary classification. `result` has shape `[batch_size,1]`. So if you are doing `argmax()` you will always get `0`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> result = np.random.rand(5,1)
>>> result
array([[ 0.54719484],
       [ 0.31675804],
       [ 0.55151251],
       [ 0.25014937],
       [ 0.00724972]])
>>> result.argmax(axis=-1)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> (result > 0.5).astype(int)
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]])
>>>
```

Comment: Woo.. That's awesome. I didn't know about that. Thank you so much. Now I got that accurately.