# Why does using text instead of glyphs prevent my neural network from learning?

Tags: go, machine-learning, text

I'm following a little tutorial with an example Neural Network implementation from [here](https://github.com/sausheong/gonn).

This originally used the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) but I've attempted to modify it for text use instead (future goal is to categorize text messages).

Here's what I have to convert a string into an array of double-precision floating point numbers:

```
func dataFromText(text string) (data []float64) {
    data = make([]float64, 600)
    for position, character := range text {
        data[position] = float64(int(character))
    }
    return data
}
```

If the string *isn't* 600 characters the array will just add a series of zeroes to the end.

I've also modified a prediction function:

```
func predictFromText(net Network, text string) int {
    input := dataFromText(text)
    output := net.Predict(input)
    matrixPrint(output)
    best := 0
    highest := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < net.outputs; i++ {
        if output.At(i, 0) > highest {
            best = i
            highest = output.At(i, 0)
        }
    }
    return best
}
```

Then how I train the network:

```
count := 1500
fmt.Println("Training...")
net := CreateNetwork(600, 200, 2, 0.15)
strings := make([]string, count)
target := make([][]float64, count)
for a := 0; a < count; a++ {
    strings[a], target[a] = someRandomPair()
}
for epoch := 0; epoch < 5; epoch++ {
    for index, s := range strings {
        net.Train(dataFromText(s), target[index])
    }
    fmt.Println("Epoch:", epoch+1)
}
```

This line:

```
strings[a], target[a] = someRandomPair()
```

Will generate a String and a float64 array. Both are decided on a boolean random generator. If true, then it will return a string: "This is a test message." and float array {0.01, 0.99} and if false: (string is random and taken from "/usr/share/dict/words") and float array is {0.99, 0.01}.

When I begin to actually make predictions:

```
fmt.Println("Testing:", os.Args[2])
prediction := predictFromText(net, os.Args[2])
fmt.Println("Prediction:", prediction)
```

Results:

```
"This is a test message." -> (0.963765005571003, 0.03361956184092902)
 Prediction: 0
"I don't even know." -> (0.963765005571003, 0.03361956184092902)
 Prediction: 0
"Why isn't this working" -> (0.963765005571003, 0.03361956184092902)
 Prediction: 0
```

It doesn't matter what text I put in... the result is always the same... Why isn't my neural network predicting anything right?

**Edit**:
I have since also tried populating the training set with only one message:

```
strings[a] = "Message"
target[a] = []float64{0.01, 0.99}
```

This actually will vary the results when I put different messages in:

```
(0.013864548477560683, 0.9850204703692592)
(0.02411385414797107, 0.971204710177904)
```

Unfortunately, it still does NOT categorize the "Message" correctly... I expect this to be returned somehow:

```
(~0.99, ~0.01)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493375/562769 - please show me what you tried to debug the neural network

Comment: @MartinThoma I've since added what I tried in addition in my edits. First I tried with a simple message: "This is a test message" and randomized strings... then I tried one message and one message only.

Comment: Did you try having only one character as an input and a simple target?

Comment: @MartinThoma Yeah one character (trained with a single float value no variance)... it still doesn't make correct predictions...

Comment: What are your weight values at initailization? What are they after training?

Comment: @MartinThoma During initialization they are randomly set it *appears* (I didn't write the actual learning part of what I have so far). All my weights after training are currently ~0.01... none have gone higher it seems.