# How to return prediction probabilities instead of one hot encoding from keras model.predict()?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to load a pre-trained model and pass an image to `model.predict()` in keras to predict the probabilities of each class. However, instead of probabilities, I get something like one hot encoding:

`[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

[image: Code Snippet]

What should I do to return the probabilities of each class instead of one hot encoding?

Here is the source code for the pre-trained model:

https://github.com/usmannazir/ChestX/blob/master/4Cnn_keras.ipynb

Please someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that there's a problem? If the task (data) isn't ambiguous, then a well-trained model will output probabilities very close to a one-hot encoding; and when printing 0.000001 will be rounded to 0.0 and 0.9999999 will be rounded to 1.0.

Comment: @Peteris It displays the same all the time irrespective of whichever image I pass to model.predict(). You can try it out on your system as well, as it is a small code. I just tried with dog image it displays the same result . I just wonder what could be the issue.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode ; plus, you say you use `model.predict()`, while in your (extremely hard to read) image-of-code you seem to use `model.predict_proba` - please **be consistent**

Comment: You are probably forgetting to normalize the input images by dividing by 255.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding of possible reasons for this, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493375/9471881).

However quick things you can check are:

- Whether you are **preprocessing** the images for prediction in the same way as the training image samples were preprocessed (for instance: normalising pixel values within `[0,1]` range)
- Whether the model is actually trained correctly (to ensure this, try training the same model again and monitor accuracy if it is fluctuating or not)

Answer (score 0):

`print (classes[int (one_hot_predictions[2][2])])`

Should do the trick to return a class name instead of integers