# Neural network always predicts the same class in each epoch

Tags: python, mnist

I'm trying to implement a mnist classifier with DNN. However, the result I got is quite strange.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwCFp.jpg)

In this epoch, this model can only predict number '0' correctly, and incorrect prediction for all the other numbers. This model could only predict a specific number for each epoch. (such predicted number is different in each epoch)

This is how I get the dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import time

x, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True)
x = (x/255.).astype('float32')
y = to_categorical(y)

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
```

For this part, this is my model. A two-hidden-layers DNN with activation functions of Relu and softmax, Cross entropy loss for the error function.
I'm not really sure if my backpropagation is correct or not. I think something is wrong here.

```
import numpy as np


class NN():
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_1_size, hidden_2_size, output_size):
        self.input_data = np.random.randn(1, input_size)
        self.w1 = np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_1_size)
        self.b1 = np.random.randn(1, hidden_1_size)
        
        self.w2 = np.random.randn(hidden_1_size, hidden_2_size)
        self.b2 = np.random.randn(1, hidden_2_size) 

        self.w3 = np.random.randn(hidden_2_size, output_size)
        self.b3 = np.random.randn(1, output_size)


    def Sigmoid(self, z):
        return np.clip(1 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z)), 1e-8, 1 - (1e-7))

    def Softmax(self, z):
        y_logit = np.exp(z - np.max(z, 1, keepdims=True))
        y = y_logit / np.sum(y_logit, 1, keepdims=True)
        return y

    def Relu(self, z):
        return np.maximum(z, 0)

    def acc_test(self, input_data):
        tmp_h1 = self.Relu(input_data.dot(self.w1) + self.b1)
        tmp_h2 = self.Relu(self.h1_out.dot(self.w2) + self.b2)
        tmp_out = self.Softmax(self.h2_out.dot(self.w3) + self.b3)
        return tmp_out

    # Feed Placeholder

    def forward(self, input_data):

        self.input_data = input_data
        self.h1_out = self.Relu(input_data.dot(self.w1) + self.b1)
        self.h2_out = self.Relu(self.h1_out.dot(self.w2) + self.b2)
        self.output_layer = self.Softmax(self.h2_out.dot(self.w3) + self.b3)

    # Backward Propagation

    def backward(self, target):

        # corss_entropy loss derivative
        Loss_to_z_grad = (self.output_layer - target) # correct

        self.b3_grad = Loss_to_z_grad
        self.w3_grad = self.h2_out.T.dot(Loss_to_z_grad) # correct



        Activation_2＿grad = Loss_to_z_grad.dot(self.w3.T) # correct
        Activation_2_grad[Activation_2_grad<0] = 0

        self.b2_grad = Activation_2＿grad
        self.w2_grad = self.h1_out.T.dot(Activation_2＿grad)

        
        Activation_1＿grad = Activation_2＿grad.dot(self.w2.T)
        Activation_1_grad[Activation_1_grad<0] = 0     

        self.b1_grad = Activation_1＿grad
        self.w1_grad = self.input_data.T.dot(Activation_1＿grad)


    # Update Weights
    def update(self, learning_rate=1e-06):
        self.w1 = self.w1 - learning_rate * self.w1_grad
        self.b1 = self.b1 - learning_rate * self.b1_grad

        self.w2 = self.w2 - learning_rate * self.w2_grad
        self.b2 = self.b2 - learning_rate * self.b2_grad

        self.w3 = self.w3 - learning_rate * self.w3_grad
        self.b3 = self.b3 - learning_rate * self.b3_grad

    # Loss Functions
    def cross_entropy(Y, Y_prediction):
        return -(np.matmul(Y, np.log(Y_prediction)) + np.matmul((1-Y), np.log(1-Y_prediction)))

    def print_accuracy(self):
        correct = 0
        loss = 0
        for i in range(y_val.shape[0]):
            self.acc_test(x_val[i])
            index = self.output_layer
            one_hot = 0
            for check in range(y_val[i].shape[0]):
                if y_val[i][check] == 1:
                    one_hot = check
                    break
            if np.argmax(index) == one_hot:
                correct += 1
                # print('correct: ',check)
            # else:
                # print('incorrect: ', check)
        print('accuracy = ', correct/y_val.shape[0])
```

```
import random
 mnist_nn = NN(input_size = 784, hidden_1_size = 200, hidden_2_size = 200,output_size = 10)


 
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(2000):
        index = random.randint(0,x_train.shape[0]-1)
        mnist_nn.forward(x_train[[index]])
        mnist_nn.backward(y_train[index])
        mnist_nn.update()
    print(i)
    mnist_nn.print_accuracy()
```

The accuracy is terribly low since it can only predict one number.
I've seen this article, [Neural network always predicts the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488279/neural-network-always-predicts-the-same-class) and I did change Relu to leaky Relu, but it doesn't really work.

I think my dataset should be ok cause I use the same dataset to train a DNN with pytorch, and it works. Also, the initial value of weights and bias are random values.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a quick look over your code and if I understand it correctly, then there may be some issues:

- It seems like you want it to do multi-class classification with 10 classes, however I believe your cross entropy function looks like binary cross entropy, instead of general [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). Also, you're using matrix multiplication, whereas I think you want to sum `y * log(y_pred)` over the 10 output probabilities and then take the mean across the batch, so you end up with a scalar valued loss.
- When doing the ReLU gradient, you should clip where the actual activation is negative, not where the gradient is negative, I think. So `Activation_2_grad[Activation_2_grad<0] = 0` should be `Activation_2_grad[self.h2_out < 0] = 0`.
- The rest of the backprop looks okay.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! However I think 'Loss_to_z_grad' should be correct because of this https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pjsadows/notes.pdf. Anyway, this is the trivial thing. But all the others suggestions work! thank you so much!

Comment: Also, I found that my 'acc_test' is wrong, it should be                                                 
     tmp_h1 = self.Relu(input.dot(self.w1) + self.b1) and tmp_h2 = self.Relu(tmp_h1.dot(self.w2) + self.b2)