# Keras model is only predicting one label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have developed a paraphrase detection model (Yes/ No) which gets two phrases as input and is supposed to return whether it's paraphrased version or not.

Based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488279/neural-network-always-predicts-the-same-class) I ensured that there is no class imbalance in training dataset:

[image: Train labels]

This is my model:

```
left_input = Input(shape=(120, ))
right_input = Input(shape=(120, ))
left_embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 120, input_length=max_length)(left_input)
right_embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 120, input_length=max_length)(right_input)
left_lstm = LSTM(120, input_shape=(1, 120))(left_embedding)
right_lstm = LSTM(120, input_shape=(1, 120))(right_embedding)
concat = concatenate([left_lstm, right_lstm], name='Concatenate')
model_output = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(concat)

model = Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=model_output, name='Final_output')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.summary()
```

These are the predictions my model made:

[image: Predictions]

[image: Confusion matrix]

Can anybody point out what is the problem here?

**Update-1**
Bu replacing "softmax" with "sigmoid", I get following values (all same):

[image]

Comment: Which values can `Dense(1, activation='softmax')` output? It is only `1`, your network only outputs `1` in the end.

Comment: @Frightera I used one because it will be either 0 or 1. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Btw I did try using 2 but then I get the error in model.fit "ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))."

Comment: Your labels should be one hot encoded for this, or you to need use `sigmoid` instead of `softmax`.

Comment: So I used sigmoid but effectively it does the same thing. Insead of all 1's it is predicting all values to be 0.472. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @Frightera Same is the case if I use OneHotEncode, it just predicts the same two values for all the labels.

Comment: Model configuration is correct for this task (BCE + Sigmoid + 1 neuron), there might be an issue with data or model architecture (units etc.)

Comment: @Frightera The data is (guaranteed) correct because it is provided by an external party. Can you please suggest what could be a problem with model architecture? I have a fairly simple model in place currently.